# Catch a foreign key error in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to catch

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Error

I want to show a message to users that they cannot delete this row when they delete

```
try
{
    $success=$db->query("DELETE FROM tableName WHERE ID=1");                                
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
     echo "You cannot delete this row";
}
```

Comment: Usually, if you let users to delete some resources, your app should be able to delete all the dependencies of that resource. You cannot show a button to the user which is not doing what the user expects..

Comment: @MateiMihai :  if the user added some data by mistake , they have delete it.   Otherwise its not a user friendly application

Comment: I agree, but I think it is not a user-friendly app also when they are not adding data by mistake but the application is not letting them to delete what they want.. Imagine you have a resource with 20 dependencies which are also depending one on each other.. what happens then? the user must guess what to delete first in order to be able to delete what he wanted in the first place

Comment: You can check this also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744190/handling-foreign-key-exceptions-in-php

Answer (score 4):

Check value of success and proceed:

```
try {
    $success = $db->query("DELETE FROM tableName WHERE ID=1");                         

    if(!$success) {
        $error = "You cannot delete this row";
        throw new Exception($error);
    }      
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: showing Database Error    ( Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails )    and last showing   " You cannot delete this row"

Comment: Also I put header location, to goto another page ,inside catch {}   but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Check return of query; if false query for specific DB error number and/or message. Then take appropriate action. Something like this - [Is there any way to catch MySQL and database errors in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120589/is-there-any-way-to-catch-mysql-and-database-errors-in-php)

Or if you are running PDO, catch specific PDOException and query for the DB error.

The above should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I used code ->     if (!$db->query("DELETE FROM tableName WHERE ID=1"))
    {
        echo "an error occured during query".$db->error;
    }                         Not showing error

Comment: IF you do not have any error on return and no exception, then there is no error. Do you actually have a foreign key?